# How can you add the ID to the content type fields?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

All I see are classes, and from my understanding seems that there is nothing in the variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default template_preprocess_field doesn't initialize the attributes array, so you don't see it when viewing the variables with the Devel module. You can achieve this and any other attributes by adding it in a [template_preprocess_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7) from your themes template.php file. When added it will get output to the field in [template_process_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_process_field/7). Here's a generic example of adding an attribute to a field. Swap all caps items for your use case...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field().
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  $content_type = $variables['element']['#bundle'];
  $view_mode = $variables['element']['#view_mode'];
  $field_name = $variables['element']['#field_name'];

  switch ($field_name) {
    // We make sure it only effects the correct field ...
    case 'FIELD_MACHINE_NAME':

      // ... and, assuming you want to limit the where an id is used, we only add on a certain content type's full node page.
      if ($view_mode === 'full' && $content_type === 'CONTENT_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME') {
          $variables['attributes_array']['id'] = 'my-id';
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Am I right in understanding I have to do the switch/break cycle for all my fields? Any way to address all fields in the specific content type at once? No problem in doing as you suggested, but I have 30+ fields to address. I'll try this tomorrow, please be patient for I'll report back.

Comment: Great, I had no doubts about it working, just repeated the case/break snip for all my fields.

Comment: You could change the switch to test for the `$content_type` variable, change the case to the content type machine name and remove the content type check within the case statement. That would allow this code to run on every field at once. In that case you would want a more programatic way of assigning an ID, like using the field's css name...           `$variables['attributes_array']['id'] = $variables['field_name_css'];`
... A couple huge notes on this. One, if a field shows up twice on a page you'll have invalid html. Two, ID's are for javascript hooks. Use the class for styling.

Comment: Thank you. I am using the IDs for anchors inside the page. I have done most of the fields with the single switch, but I'll try your second suggestion for learning. I'm sorry I can't upvote you as I don't have enough points.